# Substract days from time stamp

Tags: hive, timestamp

I need to substract 30 days from a date in this format `yyyyMMdd` and convert it back to the same format. I do it this way.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  DATE_ADD(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20170720', 'yyyyMMdd')), -30
    ), 'yyyy-MM-dd'
  ), 'yyyyMMdd');
```

I don't like that I keep converting to and from time stamp. Can I make it shorter somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20170720', 'yyyyMMdd') - 30 * 86400, 'yyyyMMdd');
```